# MaterialButton onPressed listener not work (Flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, materialbutton

I created a layout like this, the problem is that the onPressed listener doesn't work but I can't understand why:

```
Material(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22.0)),
  color: const Color.fromRGBO(33, 63, 132, 1),
  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
  child: MaterialButton(
      height: 140.0,
      minWidth: 380.0,
      elevation: 20.0,
      color: const Color.fromRGBO(33, 63, 132, 1),
      textColor: Colors.white,
      child: Text("Chiudi sessione / Cambia utente",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: ScreenUtil().setSp(20),
          )),
      onPressed: () {
        var future = endUserSession(badgeCode, false, context);
        future.then((value) {
          setUserBadgeForDualMode("");
          setDoorStatusIntoPrefs("");
          Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const OpenDoorDualMode()));
        });
      }
      ),
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with your function call, you are not awaiting for a future value, Use it that way

```
var future = await endUserSession(badgeCode, false, context);
```

Or Try Removing it and call your function like this

```
   await endUserSession(badgeCode, false, context).then((value) async {
         await setUserBadgeForDualMode("");
         await setDoorStatusIntoPrefs("");
          Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const OpenDoorDualMode()));
        });
```

Use "await" wherever you are expecting a future value.

Comment: Also add async here   onPressed: () async{ .....}

Comment: I noticed that the problem arose when I entered MaterialButton as a child of Material,before that everything was working fine

Comment: can you share the output, maybe it help figuring out the original problem

Comment: Anyway i tried your solution and it works perfectly. Thank you so much, you save my life :)

Comment: You are welcome